# need a regex to accept numeric value which is greater than 0 and comma

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, validation

i have to check a comma separated value in which i have to allow only numeric character greater than 0 and comma below is format that i required

- -1,2,3,567,76,67,20,10

and below is the error that should not be accept by the regex

1. 0,23,344 23,
2. 0,2323,85 34
3. 344,44,00
4. sdfs,34,34,

i have used the regex

this one accept all numeric character and comma but also accept 0

```
return ( ! preg_match("/^([0-9,])+$/i", $quantity)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
```

this one accept not accept 0 at any place

```
return ( ! preg_match("/^([1-9,])+$/i", $quantity)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `explode` and `array_filter`?

Comment: i need these for csv upload where they put multiple entries in same format so for checking that information with explode and array_filter takes more time .

Comment: I wouldn't assume that using those methods is slower than a complex regex without measuring. Each is a small subset of what the regex has to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of good readable and maintainable code I'd rather stick to a validation function - something like this:

```
function validateCsv($input)
{
    foreach (str_getcsv($input) as $value) {
        if (!preg_match('#^[\d]+$#', $value)) {
            throw new \Exception('invalid CSV-value ' . $value);
        }
        if ($value <= 0) {
            throw new \Exception('invalid CSV-value ' . $value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work
`^[1-9][0-9]*$`

Comment: but may be this will not accept the comma seperated value

Comment: Maybe this way `^[1-9][0-9,]*$`

Comment: not accepting comma when i enter 23, it return false but for numeric its working

Comment: `^[1-9],?[0-9]*$|^[1-9][0-9]*,?[0-9]*$`

Comment: please check  30,00 it return false

Comment: sorry for my previous comment it returns true but it has to return false because 00 occurred in this string

Comment: i just need only numeric character which are greater than 0 for each comma separated values and there is minimum 10 comma separated value

Comment: So I don't understand the question at all. Please provide input string and the output you are expecting to get.

Comment: above i mention the condition please check the below i mention the condition which have to return false                                                        a.  **0,23,344 23**,
b.  **0,2323,85 34**
c. **344,44,00**
d. **sdfs,34,34**,

Comment: 344,44,00    
sdfs,34,34,

Answer (score 0):

If you explode the comma-separated list, the test for validity of each element becomes much easier. Something like:

```
$values = explode(',', $input);
$invalidValues = array_filter($values, function($value) {
    // do your test and return TRUE if the value is invalid, so
    // the count of the resulting array will be 0 if all were valid
    return !is_numeric($value) || $value <= 0;
});

if (count($invalidValues) == 0) {
    // everything was valid, carry on
}
```

This also gives you a list of the invalid inputs, if that would be useful for providing error messages.